# Push Notification Certificate on new Mac

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I have a query about push notification certificate if I get a new Mac. Can someone tell me how this will work.

I have an App that is LIVE and it has push notification working via OneSignal. I generated the certificates via my current Mac and uploaded that to OneSignal.

Now, I am looking at updating this Mac since it is getting a little old. Now if I were to build that App on my new Mac, I would need to regenerate the certificates and re-upload them to OneSignal for my app to receive push notification. The problem then is, what happens to the current App on people's phone that is already live.

They won't receive the push notifications until they get the new App (after Apple has approve it etc etc). I am sure there is a simple answer that I don't know about.

Also, is it possible to take the certificate from the old Mac and use it for the new Mac?

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think if u update the certiificate on oneSignal it don't affect current live app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @Mr Jones you do not need to create new certificates. You can get your certificates from old mac.Steps are listed below

1:- Open Keychain access

2:- select certificates and select certificates for push and 
    distribution/development and right click on it then select export it.
    (one by one)

3:- Download provisioning profile from developer account

4:- move these files to new mac and double click on these one by one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, it is possible to take the certificate from the old Mac and use
  it for the new Mac.(with Private key)

  If APNS working with OLD Cert. them no need to update that, just
  reuse that cert.
- if u want to create new certificate then you have to test development APNS Cert on Development Environment(OneSignal).